# MobX with React Native: store is undefined

Tags: react-native, observable, mobx, mobx-react

This is my first go at using MobX so this may be a simpler problem than I imagine, but I'm not getting any errors with the things I've tried; the store is simply undefined wherever I try to use it. I've tried both importing the store directly into components and passing props from the main file (also with , but I'm not sure if I used that right). I've experimented with several different .babelrc file settings as well, but that doesn't seem to be an issue.

Here is the UserStore:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { observable } from 'mobx';

class UserStore {
  @observable info = {
    username: "bob",
    password: "secret",
    email: "bob@email.com"
  }
}

const userStore = new UserStore()
export default userStore;
```

Here is a simplified App.js:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Profile from './app/Profile.js';
import { UserStore } from './app/UserStore.js';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      page: 'Profile',
    }
  }

  changePage(){
    switch (this.state.page) {
      case "Profile":
        return <Profile logout={this.logout.bind(this)} userStore={UserStore}/>;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.changePage()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And here is a simplified Profile.js:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react/native';

@observer
export default class Profile extends Component {

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.userStore);
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Profile Page</Text>
        <Text>username: {props from store go here}</Text>
        <Text>password: {props from store go here}</Text>
        <Text>email: {props from store go here}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

All I'm trying to do right now is get the pre-defined observable "info" object from the store to the Profile.js component and display that information. This is being way more difficult than it should be - any insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm facing almost the exact same issue, but I wasn't going to pass my store down through props. Is this necessary? Couldn't you import the Store in your Profile.js?

Comment: Great question! From what I've read it sounds like you should be able to do it both ways, and importing store directly may actually be preferred. Here is a good discussion on github: https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/300
Look for mweststrate's comment(s) for a better explanation. Only reason I chose to pass props was so I could have that single entry point with mobx and pass it along the chain of react-navigation via props. Hope that helps!

Comment: I've actually yet to see an example of importing a Store directly and using it. In that link, the OP's example doesn't simply inject a store. Rather, the store exports a wrapper for instantiating the component with a store prop. So... my question goes unanswered i think.

Comment: Ah, sorry, thought there was an example in there somewhere. In any case, I just tried directly importing store in another test project, and it definitely works! Whether or not it's good practice I couldn't tell you, but it seems a bit cleaner than the potentially verbose react-navigation way of passing props; basically every page you need information on you just have to include:
import { observer } from 'mobx-react/native';
import Store from './Store.js';
with @observer above the component class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you declared `export default userStore;` in UserStore.js

Try changing the way you import in App.js by removing the `{}`:

`import UserStore from './app/UserStore.js';`

`{}` is needed only if you want to do a named import. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Importing_defaults) is a good read if you want to know more.

Comment: Oh goodness... of course. Haha Some days you just need another pair of eyes. Thank you very much, works like a charm!

Comment: You saved me !!

Comment: Removing the `default` from export and making it a named export is better. Default exports can be renamed on import so they are a footgun.